# why the edge function give segmentation error

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write I could that can edit images according to Sobel filter algorithm but it still gives me segmentation error when I try to use edges function but I couldn't know the reason can any one tell me what is the error ?

the target of such project is to turn any picture to be edged by multiplying each pixel colors values with a corresponding matrix but when I do so I got segmentation fault error (core dump) what shall I do ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "helpers.h"
//#include "bmp.h"

//variables for
//int Gx_sum_red, Gx_sum_blue, Gx_sum_green, Gy_sum_red, Gy_sum_blue, Gy_sum_green;



// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //int height_edited = 0;
    //int width_edited = 0;
    //printf("height is %i, width is %i and RGBTRIPLE IS %i for green, %i for blue and %i for red\n", height, width,
    //        image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtBlue, image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtGreen, image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtRed);
    //RGBTRIPLE temp
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //int height_edited = height / 2;
    //int width_edited = width / 2;
    //printf("height is %i, width is %i and RGBTRIPLE IS %i for green, %i for blue and %i for red\n", height, width,
    //        image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtBlue, image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtGreen, image[height_edited][width_edited].rgbtRed);
    RGBTRIPLE temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
        {
            temp.rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            temp.rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temp.rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][width - j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][width - j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][width - j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][width - j].rgbtBlue = temp.rgbtBlue;
            image[i][width - j].rgbtGreen = temp.rgbtGreen;
            image[i][width - j].rgbtRed = temp.rgbtRed;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && (j != 0 || j != width - 1))
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && (j != 0 || j != width - 1))
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6;
            }
            else if (j == 0 && (i != 0 || i != height - 1))
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6;
            }
            else if (j == width - 1 && (i != 0 || i != height - 1))
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed) / 6;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                        image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                         image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                       image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 9;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}


// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int red_avg, blue_avg, green_avg;
    int fGx_sum_red, fGx_sum_blue, fGx_sum_green, fGy_sum_red, fGy_sum_blue, fGy_sum_green;
    int red_sum, blue_sum, green_sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //calculating the Gx sum of red values
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2);//
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0)
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * -1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * -1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * -1);//
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1)+ (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2);//

            }
            else if (i == 0 && (j != 0 || j != width - 1))
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2) +
                              (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) +
                               (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) +  (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) +
                                (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && (j != 0 || j != width - 1))
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1) +
                              (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) +
                               (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) +
                                (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * -1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * -1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * -1);//
            }
            else if (j == 0 && (i != 0 || i != height - 1))
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * -1) +
                              (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * -1) +
                               (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * -1) +
                                (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
            }
            else if (j == width - 1 && (i != 0 || i != height - 1))
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2) +
                              (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2) +
                               (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2) +
                                (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2);//
            }
            else
            {
                fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1) +
                              (image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * 2) +
                              (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
                fGx_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1) +
                               (image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 2) +
                               (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);
                fGx_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1) +
                                (image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 2) +
                                (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
                fGy_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * -1) +
                              (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * 1);//
                fGy_sum_blue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * -1) +
                               (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue * 1);//
                fGy_sum_green = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * -1) + (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen * -2) + (image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * -1) +
                                (image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen * 1) + (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen * 2) + (image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen * 1);//
            }


            printf("red_sum is %i and %i, blue_sum is %i and %i and green_sum is %i and %i\n", fGx_sum_red, fGy_sum_red, fGx_sum_blue, fGy_sum_blue,
                    fGx_sum_green, fGy_sum_green);
            //calculating sum of Gx and Gy for each color
            red_sum = (fGx_sum_red * fGx_sum_red) + (fGy_sum_red * fGy_sum_red);
            blue_sum = (fGx_sum_blue * fGx_sum_blue) + (fGy_sum_blue * fGy_sum_blue);
            green_sum = (fGx_sum_green * fGx_sum_green) + (fGy_sum_green * fGy_sum_green);
            printf("red_sum is %i, blue_sum is %i and green_sum is %i\n", red_sum, blue_sum, green_sum);

            red_avg = sqrt(red_sum);
            blue_avg = sqrt(blue_sum);
            green_avg = sqrt(green_sum);
            printf("red_avg is %i, blue_avg is %i and green_avg is %i\n", red_avg, blue_avg, green_avg);

            //updating colors values
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red_avg > 255 ? 255 : red_avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue_avg > 255 ? 255 : blue_avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green_avg > 255 ? 255 : green_avg;
            printf("image[i][j].rgbtRed is %i, image[i][j].rgbtBlue is %i and image[i][j].rgbtGreen is %i, i and j are %i and %i \n",
            image[i][j].rgbtRed, image[i][j].rgbtBlue, image[i][j].rgbtGreen, i, j);
            //continue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Which is the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault? Run the program in a debugger to find out. The debugger can also be used to help trace where the problem may be occuring. Also run the program in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help find any memory issues that can result in seg faults.

Comment: Recheck what?  You still have not run the program in a debugger to find out the exact line of code that triggers the crash. Also please post the logs as text not as an image.

Comment: I added the result of debugger but it gives no errors it just gave the errors when I run it without debugger

Comment: Please post the logs as text.

Comment: you mean debug50 ?

Comment: Subject says "edge" but code has "edges".  Update question to ensure it's correct.  Congratulations on the job security.  Your code is unreadable to me.  Refactor it to get rid of all that duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i == 0` you try to deference  `image[i - 1][j]` in this block of code.  This is out of bound access to the image array and trigger a segfault for me:

```
} else if (i == 0 && (j != 0 || j != width - 1)) {
   fGx_sum_red = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * 0) ...
```

By analogy (in other words I have no idea if that is correct algorithm) replace `i - 1` with `i` in that block.